# How to repeat a fixed size table on each page in SSRS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a small table (fixed number of headers and rows) in an SSRS report I need to repeat on each page of my report.  My report is driven off of a larger table that spans multiple pages, I need the smaller static table to repeat on each page.  Is it possible to achieve this without embedding the smaller table in the main table header row?